# Unicode support in R language pattern matching

Tags: r

I'm trying to run the following pattern match in R:

`pattern = "/(?:[\p{L}\p{M}]){1,255}+/u"`

`outData <- subset(inData, grepl(pattern, b, perl = TRUE))`

but I am getting the error:

`Error: '\p' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""/(?:[\p"`

The pattern is to look for:

- letters including any diacritics
- between 1 and 255 of these characters

Is there a way to get R to recognise UNICODE pattern matching? Thanks.

Comment: Backslash is an escape character in R strings. You need to escape it (or use raw strings) to use it. So write `\\p{…}` instead of `\p{…}`. Furthermore, don’t put slashes around your regular expression — and you cannot pass flags after it either.

Comment: Thanks Konrad. That solved the error message but my pattern matching doesn't work. It seems to pass if *any* of the characters specified exist in the pattern as opposed to *only* those characters. For example, I changed it to:

pattern = "(?:[\\s\\d]){1,255}+"

and instead of matching strings containing *only* spaces and digits, it returns any string string which contains spaces or digits along with any other character.

Comment: Missed the leading ^ and trailing $ <slaps forehead>

Comment: Or use [raw strings](https://r4ds.github.io/bookclub-r4ds/raw-strings.html) ...

Comment: @Roland Right, like I said in my initial comment. ;-)